# How can i create theme's block width should be configured from dynamically

Tags: theming

I want to develop a drupal theme, where

> The theme should be develop in a way that the number of the columns of
>   the theme and the width of the columns can be configured from the
>   Admin area.

Can anyone guide me how to approach in theme development ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a theme thats already done this...

http://drupal.org/project/adaptivetheme

http://drupal.org/project/omega/